# how to change a component without rendering the other component in reactjs and react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, user-experience, react-router-dom

i have three component Header,Sidebar,and another one is the center . the center fetch data(all datas-post). In each post there will be a button to see present full post . now the full-post component will be replacing the all post-component. I dont want to render all other component. Just want to render the full-post component.Now How can I do this.
My app.js containing the three main component

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <ApolloProvider client = {client} >
        <div >
          <div className="row">
            <SideBar store={store} />
            <Center store={store} />
            <RightSlidePanel store={store}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ApolloProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

center.js component

```
  render(){

    return (
      <Provider store = {this.store}>
        <div className="center-bar nine columns ">
          <div className="row">
              <CenterHeader />
              <PostContent />
              <RightSide />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
```

now all the post are in `postContent` component  . Now A component `postdetail` will be there which when a button will be click it will replace the `postContent` in this `center` component

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @Colin please check I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a route for each post that is rendered via url parameters. 
Notice :id for rendering a specific post. When that post is reached it can fetch its needed data as well.

```
  render () {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/posts'}
          render={() => {
            return (
              <BlogSummaryList
                posts={this.state.blogPosts}
              />
            )
          }}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/posts/:id'}
          component={BlogPost}
        />
    )
  }
```

Comment: what is this `withBlogPostData(blogPost)`? I am thinking it may be a component?

Comment: Actually  using simply route will display just the blogpost component what about the sidebar and header and alll

Comment: its a higher order component. The header and sidebar should not be part of a route, they should be part of the outer context.

Comment: where this route will be then? in the above  question code>

Comment: in my code I had routes like this: index routes to Home (/posts) and then within the home component i had the two routes above

Comment: you can look here for more detail, but its a lot more code: https://github.com/mcpengelly/react-blog/blob/develop/src/components/Home.js

Comment: okay in your code example . Where I will add the  header.sidebar component?just outside of the `<Switch>` inside render method or any other place?

Comment: In my case i used the app component to render a navbar and any child components that were passed in. Then i passed in my routes as children like in these two files. https://github.com/mcpengelly/react-blog/blob/develop/src/App.js
and https://github.com/mcpengelly/react-blog/blob/develop/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much this example really helped me ...it is working super fine

Comment: Glad the examples helped! :)